# Calendar on a NFC tag

Tags: android, calendar, tags, nfc

is there a way where I can display my calendar when I scan a NFC tag? I'm new to android and I was wondering if it is possible to code a nfc tag that when someone scans a tag it displays calendar and the events.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this App will allow you to program an NFC tag to do just that: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher

I think it used to be called NFC Tasker, Now it has the name NFC Trigger.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wanted to write a code to make it do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Android Application Records](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar). Such a record inside an NDEF message on an NFC tag allows you to start a specific app.